# Move li element with javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I would like to move a li element after a list of li with the same class, is that possible?

```js
$("li#anonymous_element_2").insertAfter("li.amscheckout-row:last");
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<li class="amscheckout-row"> </li>
<li class="amscheckout-row"> </li>
<li class="amscheckout-row"> </li>
<li class="fields" id="anonymous_element_2"> </li>
<li class="amscheckout-row"> </li>
<li class="amscheckout-row"> </li>
<li class="amscheckout-row"> </li>
<li class="amscheckout-row"> </li>
```

Comment: [That works](https://jsfiddle.net/mcxr3r2d/), what's the issue?

Comment: You may be able to achieve what you want with `CSS`, using the flexbox order property? https://jsfiddle.net/sol_b/42b2ct0v/1/

Comment: Probably OP is including the script part before the html, so the selectors don't find anything. Try `jQuery(document).ready(function() { jQuery("li#anonymous_element_2").insertAfter("li.amscheckout-row:last"); })`.

Comment: Please be aware that `li` is only allowed as a direct child element of either `ul` or `ol`.

Answer (score 2):

jQuery has a built in `last()` function:

```js
var elementToMove = $('#anonymous_element_2');
var targetPosition = $('.amscheckout-row').last();

elementToMove.insertAfter(targetPosition);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<li class="amscheckout-row">1</li>
<li class="amscheckout-row">2</li>
<li class="amscheckout-row">3</li>
<li class="fields" id="anonymous_element_2">4</li>
<li class="amscheckout-row">5</li>
<li class="amscheckout-row">6</li>
<li class="amscheckout-row">7</li>
<li class="amscheckout-row">8</li>
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can! 
The method that should fit your requirements is: `after`.
If I understand you want to "move" and, to do that, you have to "remove/add" the element into the list of values. 
I suggest you to try this code:

```
var $liToAppend = $('li#anonymous_element_2');
var $lastLi = $('ul li:last'); // I suppose you are using the root tag UL!

// The final solution:
$liToAppend.remove();
$lastLi.after($liToAppend);
```

With jQuery you can to this in lot of ways:

```
$('li#anonymous_element_2').remove().appendTo('ul');
```

Should work too!

Answer (score 0):

Try This

```
<script>
 $("<li>Hello world!</li>").insertAfter(".amscheckout-row:last")
</script>
```